# How do I change my machine learning code to work for one image instead of an entire dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm learning machine learning from Google's "Introduction to TensorFlow" course. The course teaches how to create a separate test dataset and use the model you've created to test it's accuracy, but I wanted to do some testing on my own and the method I've been using to get the model to predict for one singular image is not working

This is the code that I've written (it works perfectly for a dataset, as was shown in the aforementioned course, but not for a single image, which is what I'm after):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fmnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

#Here is the test image that I'd like to use
index = 24
plt.imgshow(x_test[index])

#The following is a callback class
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        # Define the correct function signature for on_epoch_end
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if logs.get('accuracy') > 0.99:                 
                print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!\n")
                
                # Stop training once the above condition is met
                self.model.stop_training = True

def train_fmnist(x_train, y_train):
    
    
    # Instantiate the callback class
    callbacks = myCallback()
    
    # Define the model
    f_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([         
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)   
    ]) 
    
    # Compile the model
    f_model.compile(optimizer='adam',                   
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',                   
                  metrics=['accuracy'])     
    
    history = f_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[callbacks])

    return history

#Check accuracy of the model on test images
f_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

#Here is the code I wrote to use the model for just one image from the test dataset:
classifications = f_model.predict(x_test[index])

print(classifications[0])
print(test_labels[0])
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

```
ValueError: in user code: File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2137, in predict_function * return step_function(self, iterator) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2123, in step_function ** outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,)) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2111, in run_step ** outputs = model.predict_step(data) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2079, in predict_step return self(x, training=False) File "/opt/python/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential). Cannot iterate over a shape with unknown rank. Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential): • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32) • training=False • mask=None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

model.predict expects the inputs first dimensions to be batch size. In the case of a single image the batch size is one. If you have an image file say it is x_test[0] you need to expand its dimension to add the batch size dimension. You can do this using numpy's expand_dims as per the code below

```
import numpy as np
x=np.expand_dims(x_test[0], axis=0)
classifications = f_model.predict(x)
```